# Payload is missing from jwt token in djanog

Tags: django, jwt, token, access-token, refresh-token

I'm setting updating payload of token by following way.

```
 payloads = {
            "user": "admin" if employee.is_admin and employee.is_verified and employee.is_staff
                    else "staff" if employee.is_staff and employee.is_verified
                    else ""
        }
refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(employee)
refresh.payload.update(payloads)

acess_token = str(refresh.access_token)
refresh_token = str(refresh)
```

And when I print the payloads of token by `print(refresh.access_token.payload)`  it is showing `{'token_type': 'access', 'exp': 1703799022, 'iat': 1703763022, 'jti': '7b09308f00194f149cadd7ec6f1728cc', 'user_id': 3, 'user': 'admin'}`

I have set custom permission class as follows

```
class AdminPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_permission(self, request, view):

    print(AccessToken(request.auth).payload)
    
    STAFF_METHODS = ['GET','POST','PATCH']
    USER_METHODS = ['GET']
    
 
    if request.method in USER_METHODS:
        return True
    
    print(request.user)
        
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    
        if request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_staff and request.user.is_verified:
            return True
        
        if not request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_staff and request.user.is_verified and request.method in STAFF_METHODS: 
            return True
        
        
    return False
```

When this permission class is called `print(AccessToken(request.auth).payload)` is printing only `{'token_type': 'access', 'exp': 1703799137, 'iat': 1703763137, 'jti': '402403953a4d4810b3d453385d005330'}`. `user_id` and `user` field is missing from the token. I don't know where I went wrong. How can I solve this?

I'm passing Bearer token.